# ls pagination on MontaVista with BusyBox

Tags: ls, busybox, pager

I'm logged into an IP Phone running MontaVista with a very stripped down BusyBox binary (by stripped down, I mean the OEM has removed almost all of its functionality, except the basics like `cat`, `ls` etc).

I'm doing an `ls -l` on a directory and there are thousands of files. I need to be able to pause the file list on the end of each page of results.

Normally I would do this with `ls -l|more` or even `ls -l|less` but of course, `more` and `less` are not present on this phone.

Are there any other low-level ways of making `ls` paginate? My only other option is to write the output to a file and then `tftp` it off the server and open it on a proper computer, but this is a very roundabout (and slow) method of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are accessing the device through a terminal, you can use GNU Screen to connect; you can then use Screen's scrolling to see the output.

If the system has vi installed, you can try outputting the command to a file and reading it with vi.

If those don't suffice, you can make a bash script to output a screen's worth then pause.

```
for line in $(ls -l); do
  echo "$line"
  i=$((i+1))
  [ "$i" = 50 ] && read && i=0
done
```

This prints 50 lines and waits for you to press enter before printing the next 50.

Comment: Perfect - that little script worked brilliantly. Slow, but that's OK as I need to scan the files by eye anyway.

Comment: (Ah, I didn't see the `sleep` command in there, no wonder)

Comment: Yeah - originally, I had a `read` there. It took a little bit to figure out why it wasn't working. You might be able to use `read < /dev/console`.

Comment: Okay, edited to be better.